# Modifying default configuration for react app

Tags: reactjs

I am starting with a new code base and I am a little confused. I look in package.json and specialized '.' configuration files and I don't see any configuration. Yet the components return JSX so there is some kind of transpiling happening. The build goes to a specific folder. There is a port assigned that gets assigned on 'npm start'. I could go on and on but the point is all of this seems to be 'normally' configured. But I am not sure where to look for this configuration or how best to modify it. For instance what if I want to modify the 'configuration' to use TypeScript? Or add testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These configurations are by default created when you create a react project and the role of the package.json file is to show you the versions that you are using if you will include externals library to use inside your app.

for using typescript or using anything external and including it inside your app then you will include it using npm which is responsible to add your new packages inside the node_modules folder and the version number inside your package.json.

for using test this will be normal files you will create inside your app and use npm run test and it will show for you the results.

for making your project to be typescript then you will use

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript

# or

yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript
```

Comment: What about adding typescript or testing to an existing project?

Comment: Well, to add typescript to the existing application you need to follow these steps npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest.
# or.
yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest. and for adding a test to your app, you can follow the approach of making a test folder where you want to use the test approach and name your files to componentName.test.js you can read more about testing and how to implement it with jest https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react